# React Native Animated Rotating Circles with scale dependency

Tags: react-native, animation, geometry, scale

I have an animated component where you can select one of seventeen circles. It looks like this so far:

[image: App]

**I would like to add an animation that scales the circle as it gets closer to the center. How do I do that?**

Until now I tried to calculate the x value of the circle as `Math.sin(index*deltaTheta*Math.PI/180 + Math.PI)*Radius` and use this value in a functions which maps to a scaling factor (e.g. a gaussian). This fails because the x value does not change, because I am using CSS transform rotate.

Then I tried to use a different `interpolating` range for every single circle, but did not achieved a satisfying result.

---

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, PanResponder, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Circle from './Circle'

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width

const Container = styled(Animated.View)`
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
`

const gaussFunc = (x, sigma, mu) => {
  return 1/sigma/Math.sqrt(2.0*Math.PI)*Math.exp(-1.0/2.0*Math.pow((x-mu)/sigma,2))
}
const myGaussFunc = (x) => gaussFunc(x, 1/2/Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI), 0)

const circles = [{
  color: 'red'
}, {
  color: 'blue'
}, {
  color: 'green'
}, {
  color: 'yellow'
}, {
  color: 'purple'
}, {
  color: 'black'
}, {
  color: 'gray'
}, {
  color: 'pink'
}, {
  color: 'lime'
}, {
  color: 'darkgreen'
}, {
  color: 'crimson'
}, {
  color: 'orange'
}, {
  color: 'cyan'
}, {
  color: 'navy'
}, {
  color: 'indigo'
}, {
  color: 'brown'
}, {
  color: 'peru'
}
                ]

function withFunction(callback) {
  let inputRange = [], outputRange = [], steps = 50;
  /// input range 0-1
  for (let i=0; i<=steps; ++i) {
    let key = i/steps;
    inputRange.push(key);
    outputRange.push(callback(key));
  }
  return { inputRange, outputRange };
}

export default class SDGCircle extends Component {
  state = {
    deltaTheta: 360/circles.length,
    Radius: 0, // radius of center circle (contaienr)
    radius: 25, // radius of orbiting circles
    container: { height: 0, width: 0 },
    deltaAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
  }

  offset = () => parseInt(this.state.container.width/2)-this.state.radius

  _panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    nMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderGrant: () => {
      const { deltaAnim } = this.state
      deltaAnim.setOffset(deltaAnim._value)
      deltaAnim.setValue(0)
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
      const { deltaAnim, scaleAnim, deltaTheta, Radius } = this.state
      deltaAnim.setValue(gestureState.dx)
      console.log(deltaAnim)
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: (event, gestureState) => {

      const {dx, vx} = gestureState
      const {deltaAnim} = this.state

      deltaAnim.flattenOffset()
      Animated.spring(deltaAnim, {
        toValue: this.getIthCircleValue(dx, deltaAnim),
        friction: 5,
        tension: 10,
      }).start(() => this.simplifyOffset(deltaAnim._value));
    }
  })

  getIthCircleValue = (dx, deltaAnim) => {
    const selectedCircle = Math.round(deltaAnim._value/(600/circles.length))
    return (selectedCircle)*600/circles.length
  }
  getAmountForNextSlice = (dx, offset) => {
    // This just rounds to the nearest 200 to snap the circle to the correct thirds
    const snappedOffset = this.snapOffset(offset);
    // Depending on the direction, we either add 200 or subtract 200 to calculate new offset position. (200 are equal to 120deg!)
    // const newOffset = dx > 0 ? snappedOffset + 200 : snappedOffset - 200; // fixed for 3 circles
    const newOffset = dx > 0 ? snappedOffset + 600/circles.length : snappedOffset - 600/circles.length;
    return newOffset;
  }
  snapOffset = (offset) => { return Math.round(offset / (600/circles.length)) * 600/circles.length; }
  simplifyOffset = (val) => {
    const { deltaAnim } = this.state
    if(deltaAnim._offset > 600) deltaAnim.setOffset(deltaAnim._offset - 600)
    if(deltaAnim._offset < -600) deltaAnim.setOffset(deltaAnim._offset + 600)
  }

  handleLayout = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    this.setState({
      Radius: nativeEvent.layout.width,
      container: {
        height: nativeEvent.layout.height,
        width: nativeEvent.layout.width
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {deltaAnim, radius} = this.state

    return (
      <Container
        onLayout={this.handleLayout}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={{
          transform: [{
            rotate: deltaAnim.interpolate({
              inputRange: [-200, 0, 200],
              outputRange: ['-120deg', '0deg', '120deg']
            })
          }]
        }}
      >
        {circles.map((circle, index) => {
          const {deltaTheta, Radius} = this.state

          return (
            <Circle
              key={index}
              color={circle.color}
              radius={radius}
              style={{
                left: Math.sin(index*deltaTheta*Math.PI/180 + Math.PI)*Radius+this.offset(),
                top: Math.cos(index*deltaTheta*Math.PI/180 + Math.PI)*Radius+this.offset(),
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{index}</Text>
            </Circle>
          )
        })}
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to scale the circles as they approach the center.  So scale is a function of x, or better yet, theta.  You need to keep track of theta.  Right now you only track dTheta, so you have no way to know which circle is on/near the top.  Once you have this value you should be able to accomplish this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI: I got a solution. The result looks like this:

[image: rotating, scaling circles]

and the source code is given by:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, PanResponder, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Circle from './Circle'

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width

const Container = styled(Animated.View)`
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
`

const gaussFunc = (x, sigma, mu) => {
  return 1/sigma/Math.sqrt(2.0*Math.PI)*Math.exp(-1.0/2.0*Math.pow((x-mu)/sigma,2))
}
const myGaussFunc = (x) => gaussFunc(x, 1/2/Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI), 0)

const circles = [{
  color: 'red'
}, {
  color: 'blue'
}, {
  color: 'green'
}, {
  color: 'yellow'
}, {
  color: 'purple'
}, {
  color: 'black'
}, {
  color: 'gray'
}, {
  color: 'pink'
}, {
  color: 'lime'
}, {
  color: 'darkgreen'
}, {
  color: 'crimson'
}, {
  color: 'orange'
}, {
  color: 'cyan'
}, {
  color: 'navy'
}, {
  color: 'indigo'
}, {
  color: 'brown'
}, {
  color: 'peru'
}]

function withFunction(callback) {
  let inputRange = [], outputRange = [], steps = 50;
  /// input range 0-1
  for (let i=0; i<=steps; ++i) {
    let key = i/steps;
    inputRange.push(key);
    outputRange.push(callback(key));
  }
  return { inputRange, outputRange };
}

export default class SDGCircle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const deltaTheta = 360/circles.length
    const pxPerDeg = 200/120


    const thetas = []
    for (const i in circles) {
      let val = i*deltaTheta*pxPerDeg
      if(i >= 9)
        val = -(circles.length-i)*deltaTheta*pxPerDeg

      thetas.push(val)
    }

    this.state = {
      deltaTheta,
      Radius: 0, // radius of center circle (contaienr)
      radius: 25, // radius of orbiting circles
      container: { height: 0, width: 0 },
      deltaAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
      thetas,
      thetasAnim: thetas.map(theta => new Animated.Value(theta)),
    }
  }

  offset = () => parseInt(this.state.container.width/2)-this.state.radius

  _panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    nMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderGrant: () => {
      const { deltaAnim, thetasAnim, thetas } = this.state
      deltaAnim.setOffset(deltaAnim._value)
      deltaAnim.setValue(0)

      const iSel = Math.round((deltaAnim._value+deltaAnim._offset)/(600/circles.length))
      for(let i=0; i<circles.length; i++) {
        let xi = i+iSel
        if(xi > 16)
          xi -= circles.length
        if(xi < 0)
          xi += circles.length
        try {
          thetasAnim[xi].setOffset(thetas[i])
        } catch(err) {console.log(xi)}
      }
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
      const { deltaAnim, scaleAnim, deltaTheta, Radius, thetasAnim } = this.state
      deltaAnim.setValue(gestureState.dx)

      for (theta of thetasAnim) {
        theta.setValue(-gestureState.dx)
      }
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: (event, gestureState) => {
      const {dx, vx} = gestureState
      const {deltaAnim, thetasAnim, deltaTheta, thetas} = this.state

      deltaAnim.flattenOffset()
      const ithCircleValue = this.getIthCircleValue(dx, deltaAnim)
      Animated.spring(deltaAnim, {
        toValue: ithCircleValue,
        friction: 5,
        tension: 10,
      }).start(() => {
        this.simplifyOffset(deltaAnim)
      });

    }
  })

  getIthCircleValue = (dx, deltaAnim) => {
    const selectedCircle = Math.round((deltaAnim._value+deltaAnim._offset)/(600/circles.length))
    return (selectedCircle)*600/circles.length
  }

  snapOffset = (offset) => { return Math.round(offset / (600/circles.length)) * 600/circles.length; }
  simplifyOffset = (anim) => {
    if(anim._value + anim._offset >= 600) anim.setOffset(anim._offset - 600)
    if(anim._value + anim._offset <= -600) anim.setOffset(anim._offset + 600)
  }

  handleLayout = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    this.setState({
      Radius: nativeEvent.layout.width,
      container: {
        height: nativeEvent.layout.height,
        width: nativeEvent.layout.width
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {deltaAnim, radius} = this.state

    return (
      <Container
        onLayout={this.handleLayout}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={{
          transform: [{
            rotate: deltaAnim.interpolate({
              inputRange: [-200, 0, 200],
              outputRange: ['-120deg', '0deg', '120deg']
            })
          }]
        }}
      >
        {circles.map((circle, index) => {
          const {deltaTheta, thetasAnim, Radius} = this.state

          /* const difInPx = index*deltaTheta*200/120 */
          let i = index
          /* if(index >= Math.round(circles.length/2)) */
          /*   i = circles.length - index */

          scale = thetasAnim[i].interpolate({
            inputRange: [-300, 0, 300],
            outputRange: [0, 2, 0],
          })

          return (
            <Circle
              key={index}
              color={circle.color}
              radius={radius}
              style={{
                left: Math.sin(index*deltaTheta*Math.PI/180 + Math.PI)*Radius+this.offset(),
                top: Math.cos(index*deltaTheta*Math.PI/180 + Math.PI)*Radius+this.offset(),
                transform: [{ scale }],
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{index}</Text>
            </Circle>
          )
        })}
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```